# remove underline in inputText in React Native

Tags: css, react-native

I cannot remove underline in input text

[image]

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I guess it should be

```
underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
```

See the related issue https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/10108

Comment: Set this as a prop, not styling.

Comment: @GOXR3PLUS how did you fixed? Please  help me out.

Comment: @Kailash Have a look [here](https://github.com/goxr3plus/react-native-guess-the-number-app/blob/7e2a0f7b9fb45544fe1de5bde44639da645ba189/src/screens/StartGameScreen.js#L82-L93) not sure if i fixed it's been time :)

Answer (score 20):

Use underlineColorAndroid property of TextInput component

```
<TextInput underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
           placeholder="type here ..">
 TXT
</TextInput>
```

Answer (score 7):

Following prop in TextField works for me

```
underlineColorAndroid='rgba(0,0,0,0)'
```

Answer (score 5):

I found another way to surcharge InputContainer styles directly on the TextInput :

```
inputContainerStyle={{borderBottomWidth:0}}
```

Comment: After many trials, this is the only one that has worked for me, on Android 4.4

Answer (score 3):

I found a simple solution

```
underlineColorAndroid='#FFF'
```

Comment: You are setting the underline color to WHITE... if your TextInput's superView background color is NOT white, then the underline will be visible. Better to use 'transparent'.

Comment: This is simple patiya system

Answer (score 2):

I agree with above answers but it produces following problem randomly

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/18214

NullPointerException:tempt to invoke virtual method 'android.graphics.drawable.Drawable android.graphics.drawable.Drawable$ConstantState.newDrawable(android.content.res.Resources)

So i get up with other solution. I added editbox style in style.xml

```
<item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

---------------------------Full code------------------------------------

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/backgroundcolor</item>
        <item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/AppEditTextStyle</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppEditTextStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.EditText">
        <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:minHeight">40dp</item>
    </style>
```

Answer (score 1):

`underlineColorAndroid="transparent"` is perfectly working for me

`<TextInput
   underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
   placeholder="Your Placeholder"
 />`

[See Discussion here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/5424)

Answer (score 0):

Following prop in TextField works for android 6 to up

```
underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
```

Following prop in TextField works for android 6 to down

```
borderWidth={0}
```

so you should both props to work in every devices

```
underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
borderWidth={0}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're still looking for a solution and `underlineColorAndroid='transparent'` doesn't do the trick then try `autoCorrect={false}`.

Example :

```
<TextInput autoCorrect={false} underlineColorAndroid='transparent' placeholderTextColor={Colors.gray} style={styles.input} autoCapitalize='characters' placeholder="Type your word" />
```

Comment: explainnation: ```underlineColorAndroid='transparent'``` will resolve the issue most of it but those whose mobile dictionary is ON it is showing that underline not textInput for these do ```autoCorrect={false}``` fix the issue or turn off your mobile or emulator dictionary

Comment: Thanks Abbas for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I have used a simple solution to that problem which works for both Android and iOS devices. However, if you're using the <**underlineColorAndroid="transparent"**> attribute, it will only work for Android devices and not for iOS devices. To make it work for iOS as well, you need to include the <**underlineColor="transparent"**> attribute.

```
<TextInput
 underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
 underlineColor="transparent"
/>
```

Answer (score -2):

I found only one way to remove underline exactly from input container:

```
<TextField
    placeholder="user@gmail.co" 
    InputProps={{ disableUnderline: true }}
/>
```

Comment: This is not in the documentation