# React Native: Unable to change color of text within <TextInput> component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm not sure why but when using the `<TextInput>` component I am unable to alter the color of the input text using the standard `style={{color: '#HEX'}}`.

Here is an example:

```
          <TextInput
            style={{
              backgroundColor: 'transparent',
              color: '#fff',
              borderBottomWidth: 0,
            }}
            keyboardAppearance={'dark'}
            keyboardType={'numeric'}
            selectionColor='#fff'
            underlineColor="rgba(0,0,0,0)"
            underlineColorAndroid="rgba(0,0,0,0)"

            placeholderTextColor="#fff"

          />
```

There is also a very annoying purple underline which I can not seem to get rid of. Is there some kind of special property I need to be using for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the text color try this `theme={{ colors: { text: '#fff' } }}`; and for the underline try `autoCorrect={false}`

code

```js
<TextInput
   theme={{ colors: { text: '#fff' } }}
   autoCorrect={false}
  />
```

Comment: You're a hero - the color change worked - unfortunately the autoCorrect={false} did not manage to fix the purple underline though

Comment: check this answer might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40478246/remove-underline-in-inputtext-in-react-native

Comment: Unfortunately not - it's an issue on iOS for me. I will give you the answer for fixing the text coloring though :) Thanks for your help